# JavaScript Encryption Tool

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, encryption

I am making an Encryption Tool for myself, being a code of JavaScript, inserted into the console( interpreter ) and run, doing what follows( The code is NOT 100% JavaScript, it is an imaginary code that refers to what I want in real JavaScript ):

```
var encrypt_f = function(z) {
    switch(z) {
        case "H":
            return "0XB";
            break;
        case "e":
            return "EWD";
            break;
        case "l":
            return "FXB";
            break;
        case "o":
            return "@RS";
            break;
        default:
            return "UNK";
            break;
    } // I will write the rest of words, I got my encryption table
}

var encrypt = function(x) {
    // Turn x into an array
    // Then make a for loop, to check for every element in the array
    // and scan the letter, then, Encrypt the letter, I've provided
    // "Hello" as a word to Encrypt, I'll do the rest
    // as of:
    // var enc = "";
    // for(.. i ..) { y = x[i]; enc += encrypt_f(y) + " ";
}
encrypt("Hello");
```

The `encrypt("Hello");` should return `0XB EWD FXB FXB @RS` as:

`0XB` being `H`

`EWD` being `e`

`FXB` being `l` - Being wrote twice as there are 2 l's in Hello

`@RS` being `o`

***NOTE: ONLY JAVASCRIPT, I want the code to be inserted into the browser console to return a string and NOT for sending data to databases or anything like that, the code is NOT written into the script tag, but being inserted into a browser, also, if you can, please make the code plain JavaScript without any external libraries( jQuery )***

Comment: What is your question?  Are you stuck on trying to loop over each letter in the string?

Comment: `x.split('')` to turn it into an array.  `a.join('')` to go back to a string.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: Actually everything I want is written in comments in the code, I want the `encrypt_f` to be constructed, and the left of `encrypt` to also be constructed...

Comment: This is not a "please code it for me" platform. No own try, no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to map a string to another you can abuse replace()

```
var mapping = {
    "H": "0XB",
    "e": "EWD",
    "l": "FXB",
    "o": "@RS",
    default: "UNK"
};


function encrypt(mapping, string){
    return string.replace(/[\s\S]/g, function(chr){
        //binding and accessing this is faster than a closure
        return this[chr] || this.default;
    }.bind(mapping));
}

encrypt(mapping, "Hello")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the string (here with a split of the string and then over the array and with map and the encoding ad callback. The result array is then joined with a space).

```js
var encrypt_f = function (z) {
        return { H: '0XB', e: 'EWD', l: 'FXB', o: '@RS' }[z] || 'UNK';
    },
    encrypt = function (x) {
        return x.split('').map(encrypt_f).join(' ');
    };

document.write(encrypt("Hello!"));
```

Comment: Inject the mapping. this will create an Object with the mapping for any call of encrypt_f()

Comment: @Thomas, like `...map(encrypt_f.bind(mapping))...`? it is possible, but it makes sense only, if the purpose is known better.

Comment: more like `var encrypt = function(x){ var mapping = { H: '0XB', e: 'EWD', l: 'FXB', o: '@RS' }; return x.split('').map(chr=>mapping[chr]||"UNK").join(' '); };` or `var encrypt = function(mapping, x){ return x.split('').map(chr => mapping[chr]||mapping.default).join(' '); };`

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Jsbin: https://jsbin.com/yiborehuju/edit?js,output

```
var encrypt = function(x) {
    var enc = "";
    x = x.split('');
    x.forEach(function(l) {
        e = encrypt_f(l);
        enc += e;
    });
    return enc;
}
```